# Jitsi VideoBridge debug using eclipse

Tags: eclipse, maven, webrtc, jitsi, jitsi-meet

Hello all as I wanted to play with the jitsi-videobridge source code I downloaded the souce from git-hub and I want to run it using eclipse IDE such that I can Know how the calls are made inside the jvb but I'm unable to build the maven project in eclipse as it has many errors. So If anyone is debugging the jvb, can you please share the steps to setup the eclipse to debug the project jitsi-videobridge from source.

The quick install is working and I have tested quite a bit, but I'm curious to know how it works.

Answer (score 1):

Videobridge build follows pretty much all maven projects: just `mvn clean package` to build a jar.  I can't comment on Eclipse, but I use it in IntelliJ all the time and don't have any problems running or debugging, if that helps.

Including some of the errors you're seeing may make it easier to help you.